# Guides, Tutorials or Books about building MacOSX GUI apps with C++ in Xcode?

Tags: c++, cocoa, xcode, macos, macos-carbon

with GUI apps I mean not just a Unix command line application, but the whole .app bundle and a full Cocoa or Carbon application.
Thanks!

PS: I wasn't totally accurate with GUI application.
I meant an application with a window and a menu, as opposed to a Unix command line application.
Actually I got to a tutorial about programming with SDL and OpenGL on MacOSX and it even has XCode templates which come with the ObjC needed to set up the menus, and it's pretty much what I was looking for.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation is to work your way through the docs at http://developer.apple.com .  There is a ton of useful material there from guides to sample code.

As for building GUI apps, I would recommend building the GUI parts with Cocoa (Objective-C).  You can still implement your logic and rest of the app with C++ (C++ and Objective-C work together). However, Cocoa is MUCH easier to work with than the older C++ based Carbon.  I would consider Carbon to be legacy.  When apple put out 10.6, a lot of the under-the-hood stuff was transitioning their codebase from Carbon to Cocoa (like the Finder, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Is C++ a requirement? Most of GUI programming for Mac is done with Objective-C or C. The book of choice is Aaron Hillegas' [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619). It's an outstanding book that will let you jump in right away.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few links I have in my bookmarks, here they are:

1. [cocoablogs.com](http://cocoablogs.com/)
2. [cocoadev.com](http://www.cocoadev.com/)

Both contain a fair amount of links to resources that can be very helpful, [cocoadev.com](http://www.cocoadev.com/) has also a set of tutorials you could follow.